# Can I customize MailChimpforSalesforce App of AppExchange?

Tags: community, appexchange, mail-chimp

Can I customize the MailChimpforSalesforce App?

I am using MailChimpforSalesforce app to integrate Salesforce and Mailchimp(MC). The MailChimpforSalesforce app is designed to offer a two-way sync between MailChimp and Salesforce.

This app, gives me the option to create an MC campaign, view MC campaign activity, create a "list new" segment, all within my Salesforce account. But I don't have the option to create a new list. I want this feature.

Can I do it? Please give me some suggestions on how to go about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mailchimp is a managed application, and any managed application does not provide you ability to tailor the application to your needs. Usually the admin options are configured as settings. You cannot achieve more than the functionality documented.

If you go to [appexchange app URL](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B3byfEAB) for Mailchimp, please see the provider section and reach out to them by email to see how they can assist you.